# Wildcard as parameter of stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, interbase, select-query

Suppose, I have a stored procedure, that accepts one parameter - id, and returns some data corresponding to this id. What if I want to retrieve all such data, like using wildcard in SELECT query? How to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a trailing '%' to your query.  Assume that `@param` is the parameter to your stored procedure:

```
declare @param2 varchar(100)
set @param2 = @param + '%'

select * from table where column like @param2
```

That will return a wildcard search beginning with the value in @param.  For partial match use `'%' + @param + '%'`

[Edit]

Based on the below clarification in the comments:

```
if @id != '*' 
begin
    select * from table where column = @id
end
else
begin
    select * from table
end
```

Comment: Your answer is about text parameter only. What if passed parameter is integer (for example, a primary key)?

Comment: That was what I thought you meant :) Do you mean if the the search parameter is 1, you want to return all primary keys including 1, 11, 112, and so on?

Comment: I mean, if I want row with id = 1, I pass 1 as the parameter, 2 -> 2 as the parameter, but what if I want all existing rows?

Comment: Thanks. I did this thing by if-else statement, but thought if there is more elegant way to do that.